# How to lock size DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking.DockPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, panel

I have DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking.DockPanel dockPanelKWBar; I draw on it my form.

```
  if (KWToolForm == null)
  {
      KWToolForm = new KWToolForm();
      KWToolForm.panelKWTools.Parent = m_DockContainerForm.dockPanelKWBar_Container;
      KWToolForm.panelKWTools.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  }
```

I don't want that user changed size of this panel.

Comment: What is the type of `dockPanelKWBar_Cointainer?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent specific panel from being resized by handling the [DockManager.StartSizing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockManager_StartSizingtopic) event;

```
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking;
//...
dockManager1.StartSizing += dockManager1_StartSizing;
//...
void dockManager1_StartSizing(object sender, StartSizingEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Panel == dockPanel1)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Refer to the [Resizing Operations](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1250) and [Controlling Resizing Operations](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1267) help-articles for more information.